# transparent background in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I developed a sample application with unity

black backgound and alpha set to 0

then I exported it to native android.

I created a custom view containing my unityplayer and I put a framelayout with a blue color in the background.

Unfortunately unity still displayin the black background and not the blue one . any ideas how to make it completely transparent for my app ?

Comment: What version of Unity are you on? Recent versions (I think 2018 onward, but maybe some late 2017 versions have it as well) allow you to select "preserve frame buffer alpha" in the player settings.

Comment: I checked preserve frame buffer alpha and on my camera settings I put solid color for the clear flags with 0,0,0,0 and it doesn't work. I have the last version of unity , if this method doesn't work with it , which version should I use ?

Comment: We're probably going to have to see some code, particularly on your Android side.

Comment: on native android there is no much code, just an xml with a framelayout containing my unityview, I think the setup should be in unity not in native android !

Comment: I am not even sure that what you are trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread, it seems like it's what you want?

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity3d-export-to-android-with-transparent-background.512129/

Comment: thank you ,I already checked this one and I used unity 2018.1 but still not working